# Errorneous output with wait() and exit() call

Tags: c, linux, wait, exit

Why is the answer of the following code always 32 for the given input?

I expected it to be 400

The code is supposed to take input from child process and pass it to parent and print inside parent.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>

int main(){
    pid_t p=fork();

    if(p>0){
            int x=-1;

            wait(&x);

            printf("sum: %d",x/255);
    }else{
            int sum=400,i;
            int n,x;

            scanf("%d",&n);
            for(i=0;i<n;i++){
                scanf("%d",&x);
                sum+=x;
            }

            exit(sum);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Input:

4

100
100
100
100

Comment: What inputs did you give this program?

Comment: @lurker sorry about that...I mentioned them now

Comment: `printf("sum: %d",x/255);` maybe you intended `x & 0xff` ? -->> `man 2 wait`

Comment: You should be using `WEXITSTATUS(x)` not `x/255` I would think.

Comment: The final piece we should note is that when you start from 400, and add 100, 4 times, you end up with 800. That's why your exit code is `800%256`=`32`, not `400%256`=`144`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems. Firstly `exit` (as clearly stated in the manpage) truncates the status you pass it to be in the range 0 to 255 (0377)

> and the value of status & 0377 is returned to the parent

Secondly you're not using the value returned by `wait` correctly. To get the child's `exit` value you're meant to use `WEXITSTATUS(x)` which returns the least significant 8 bits of the value which is the same as doing `x & 255`.

Either way, your means of passing back the value of `sum` isn't going to work as is - you're better off investigating how `pipe`s work.

Comment: `x & 255` is less likely to be correct than `x / 255`. More correct would be `x / 256`. The low 8 bits are signal and core dump. But `WIFEXITED`/`WEXITSTATUS` is best.

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley That `x & 255` part I got from the `wait` manpage...it's entirely possible I've misread it and it's referring to how `exit` truncates the value

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion on pipes. Could you explain with an example for the WEXITSTATUS part?

Comment: As mentioned in the answer, you'd write `WEXITSTATUS(x)` to get the exit code with your variable `x`, so in your code you'd have `printf("sum: %d",WEXITSTATUS(x));`